# Is there a general method to determine whether a differential equation is solvable or not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general method to determine whether a differential equation is solvable or not? I couldn't find about that in anybook. Please help.

Comment: you can search for the fix point theorem of Banach

Comment: Solvable in what sense ? And what type of DE ?

Comment: The answer to such general question is (in general) no. You might want be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous methods for solving completely integrable nonlinear PDE's, for instance by explicit transformations to linear equations, or by using the Inverse Scattering Transform (IST) method. Given a Hamiltonian system, there is no known systematic method for determining whether or not that system is integrable. Much recent work has focused on the [Painlevé test](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Painlev%C3%A9_test). If the differential equation passes the test, then it is believed that the original PDE will be solvable by inverse scattering methods. Thus, while there is as yet no systematic way to determine if a differential equation is solvable using the IST method, having the Painlevé property is a strong indicator that it will be. Hope it helps.